# Ao fazer override de um método devo chamar a implementação da super antes ou depois do meu código?

Tags: java, android

Assistindo e pesquisando alguns tutoriais na internet, me deparei com alguns código em JAVA no ANDROID, conforme abaixo:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

A classe MainActivity, basicamente está trabalhando com o acelerômetro para coletar e exibir os eixos X,Y e Z do dispostivo.

A minha dúvida, qual a diferença de estar acima ou abaixo do super.onPause() a liberação de registro do SensorManager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na maioria dos casos não faz diferença, o melhor é sempre ler a documentação do método.

A documentação de [onPause()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) apenas refere a obrigatoriedade de chamar, não diz quando.

Em caso de dúvida, parece-me lógico que,

- Nos métodos que intervêm na inicialização, como onCreate(), onStart(), onRestart() e onResume(), chamar primeiro o método da super.
- Nos métodos que intervêm na finalização, como onPause(), onStop() e onDestroy(), chamar o método da super no final.

Comment: muito obrigado pela explicação.